# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int in SQL Server 2016 (AWS)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

We are using Licensed version SQL Server Standard 2008 R2 of AWS. 
We are upgrading our database from SQL 2008 R2 (10.50.1600.1) to SQL Server 2016 (13.0.16106.4). 
After setting Compatibility level to 130, below query returns the below error.

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 22 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting expression to data type int.

Both tables wfWorkflows & wfTasks have same column WorkflowId with same data type INT, NOT NULL.

```
declare @CompanyID int = 510, @RecordPkId int = 4551138,@zoneDifference varchar(6) = null

Select Minutes = 
               (
               Select sum(isnull(TimeSpentOnTask,0)) 
               from wfTasks With(nolock) 
               inner join comAdvisers With(nolock)  on 
               comAdvisers.AdviserId = wfTasks.AdviserId 
               Where WorkflowId = wfWorkflows.WorkflowId
               )
from wfWorkflows With(nolock) 
Where companyid = @CompanyID 
And ISNULL(ClientID,AdviserID) = @RecordPkId And ISNULL(InitSave,0) <> 1;
```

---

if i comment any single column from select then i will get no error, query works fine. With all column i get error.
declare @CompanyID int = 510, @RecordPkId int = 4551138,@zoneDifference varchar(6) = null

Select Minutes = (Select sum(isnull(TimeSpentOnTask,0)) from wfTasks With(nolock) Where WorkflowId = wfWorkflows.WorkflowId),
EstMinutes = (Select sum(isnull(Duration,1)) from wfTasks With(nolock)
Where WorkflowId = wfWorkflows.WorkflowId)
from wfWorkflows With(nolock) 
Where companyid = @CompanyID And ISNULL(ClientID,AdviserID) = @RecordPkId And ISNULL(InitSave,0) <> 1

Comment: How can anyone answer without knowing what data caused the problem? Don't look for bugs, find the *value* that can't fit in an `int`

Comment: where condition in sub query causing issue. If i cast first column as bigint, its resolved.
Where cast(WorkflowId as bigint) = wfWorkflows.WorkflowId.

We have around 4000 Db components and coverting all columns into bigint is not the feasible solution.

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` means you are OK with reading dirty data. It means `don't respect locks`, not `don't take locks`. This suggests that your query already has performance issues. *Simplify* your query, comment parts and bring them back one by one until you find which one causes the overlfow.

Comment: Why ask a question at all then? If the number is too large, the number is too large. That's exactly what the error says

Comment: Joining between views, aggregate subqueries with external filtering, NOLOCK, I'd say you have a lot of issues to fix already. Especially if you have so many rows that the sum of `TimeSpentOnTask` requires a 64-bit integer

Comment: table in subquery i.e. wftask has total 3 rows & column TimeSpentOnTask has NULL in all 3 rows. Output should be 0 here but its giving error.

Comment: It's possible your query contains a structural flaw (somewhere a column/expression that is not of type `INT` and not convertible to one is getting converted) that is exhibited only under specific query plans. Changing *anything* in the query or the optimizer (such as happens when you upgrade the compatibility level) could change the way data is accessed, thereby "fixing" the problem without actually fixing it. Check that `wfWorkflows.companyid` is an `INT` and that `ClientID` and `AdviserID` are `INT`.... basically, check that *everything* is an `INT`.

Comment: All the columns here are INT, said query works fine in SQL 2008, SQL 2012, SQL 2014 but causing issue in SQL 2016.

Comment: Well, I can't immediately recall any optimizer bugs that have gotten fixed, but get your instance updated to SP1 and CU3 anyway. You're running 2016 RTM, which has some serious flaws. Beyond that, troubleshooting this will require [query plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) from the working instances and those that don't work, and scripts of the tables involved.

Comment: I have update my instance to SP1 and CU3 but problem still exists.

Comment: Then, as I stated, you're going to have to add more background information to make the problem reproducible to others, or at least understandable. The most likely cause is still an error in your query caused by the underlying data, but it's not possible to tell from the query alone.

Comment: I have more that 4000 DB components, Coverting to BIGINT is not feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Even when "everything is int", the sum can overflow int type, it's normal, look at this:

```
    declare @t table(col int);
    insert into @t values(2147483647),(2147483647);

    select sum(col)
    from @t;

    --Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
    --Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

    select sum(cast(col as bigint))
    from @t;
```

In my first select I get the error, and that's right because the result does not fit into int. In my second select I cast every summand to bigint so the sum will be bigint as well and no overflow occured.

So as the first step you should cast the summands to bigint to at least receive the result and see if it effectively can fit into int. If it cannot, it cannot on the earlier versions too and this is the question of your data. If the result is small enough to fit into int, the cause maybe the following: if you have **negative** summands, the order in which the sum is calculated metters, for example, if I do

```
2147483647 - 2147483647 + 2
```

I still fit into int, but what happens if I do it in this order:

```
2147483647 + 2 - 2147483647
```

It overflows int at the first step.
So what may happend in your case is for example parralel plan that repartition the input in different ways, so the overall result still can fit into int but one of the stream caused int overflow

Comment: I have more that 4000 DB components, Coverting to BIGINT is not feasible solution.

Comment: I didn't tell you to change a data type, you can cast it when you aggregate, in your query only, in order to receive the result and to see if it fit in int. The query from your post does not contain 4000 components, it takes 1 minute to rewrite it using cast as bigint